# new tab issue in google chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open page new tab in button click event. Here is my code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgPropertyImage"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("pro_id") %>' 
    runat="server" Height="90px"  Width="130px" CssClass="imgborder"
    ImageUrl='<%#Eval("display_photo") %>'    OnCommand="imgPropertyImage_Command" 
    BorderColor="#00CCCC"  AlternateText="" onclick="imgPropertyImage_Click" />


protected void imgPropertyImage_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img = sender as ImageButton;

    Session["Pro-ID"] = img.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect("PropertyDetails.aspx");
}
```

Comment: @HansKesting Are you sure? I'm quite confident an `ImageButton` renders as `input[type='image']`

Comment: @Curt - you're right, I deleted my comment. In any case, that extra `<a>` is not needed/used.

Comment: Did you try my answer, I have tested it and it seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

Place this javascript in your asp:content

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var windowObjectReference;

        function openRequestedPopup() {
            var windowObjectReference = window.open("PropertyDetails.aspx",
              "DescriptiveWindowName",
              "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
        }
</script>
```

in ImageButton OnClientClick

```
OnClientClick="javascript:return openRequestedPopup();"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, delete `<a>` tag.
And add this :

```
  OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>
```

in your button properties.